# Django render_to_response() with parameter names specified

Tags: django

I am not 100% sure whether this is a Django or a Python question, but I think it's got something to do with Django.

As I am new to the Django world, I am trying to establish the good habit of explicitly putting down parameter names when making function calls.

In the case of render_to_response(), I would have something like the following:

```
render_to_response(template='lend_borrow/MyAccount_mod.html',
                   dictionary={'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'profile': profile_obj},
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But with that, I got an error, "render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template'".

In order for that render_to_response() to work in my view function, I had to change it to

```
render_to_response('lend_borrow/MyAccount_mod.html',
                    {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'profile': profile_obj},
                    RequestContext(request))
```

OR

```
render_to_response('lend_borrow/MyAccount_mod.html',
                    {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'profile': profile_obj},
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**QUESTION:** Why is the first approach of calling render_to_response() giving me an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render_to_response` is a wrapper around `HttpResponse`. However, `HttpResponse` takes rendered content, not a template name. Therefore, `render_to_response` calls `render_to_string` first, and the parameter in `render_to_string` is `template_name` *not* `template`.

However, prefixing parameter names isn't necessarily "good practice". Good practice is to follow convention and convention is to not use parameter names in `render_to_response`, except for `context_instance`.

Comment: Yes, "template_name" works! Thanks.

render_to_response(template[, dictionary][, context_instance][, mimetype])

Above is the signature of render_to_response from Django's official document. I think it should read "template_name" instead of "template"

Comment: I agree with your comment on prefixing parameter names. It's just that I tend to be more cautious when it comes to relying on implicit indexes in matching parameters with values. And prefixing parameters names, in most cases, makes the code more readable and understandable. But like you, when convention kicks in, I am willing to relax this principle.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter name is `template_name`, not `template`.